# Generating multiple sheets in a single excel document using Grails Export plugin

Tags: excel, grails, export

I'm using Export plugin for Grails(http://www.grails.org/plugin/export) to generate excel sheets. Now I need to create multiple sheets in the same Excel document and if possible, name those individual sheets. Searching around in internet, couldn't find any solution to this problem. Can someone please help on this?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There [looks to be no way](https://fisheye.codehaus.org/browse/grails-plugins/grails-export/trunk/src/groovy/de/andreasschmitt/export/exporter/DefaultExcelExporter.groovy?r=HEAD) of doing this currently with that plugin.

Your best bet would be to add it as a feature request on the [JIRA for that module](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS/component/13865) -- or better yet -- take the module, add that functionality and submit a patch to the JIRA.

Or you're going to have to look for another way of exporting XLS data.

Comment: Yeah it seems there's no other way than writing own functionality. Solved the problem by using PDF export instead. Thanks anyways :)